# Compress on code json string and return to client

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, compression

I have a `ASP.NET MVC` Controller `C#` and inside I have the following method:

```
public JsonResult PlayersData()
 {
     List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

     // here some code to fill players list
     // ...

     return Json(players, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

I would like to send the Json compressed, I mean the List because the json is heavy about 12MB.

I **don't want to enable IIS compression**, I need to do it within the same code.

> Any clue?

Comment: How could you possibly use 12MB of json in a view?

Comment: Is not for a view, this method is available for other purpose. Im using it just like an API.